# fopen returns non-null pointer even though file does not exist

Tags: c, file

I have a Hex file whose contents are like below:

0x14000800
0x52100000
0xD503201F
0xD503201F
0x0030A308
0x0032D138
0x00000000
0x00000000
0x00000000
0x00000000

I need to open and read this file. Below is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
 char ch, boot_rom_golden[16];
 FILE *myFile = NULL;

 myFile = fopen("/prj/vlsi/tests/boot_rom_fail/src/apps_proc0/sm6140_rom.a52100000_ROM_FULL.hex", "r");

 if (myFile == NULL) {
    printf("Error Reading File\n");
    exit(0);
  }

while ((ch = fgetc(myFile)) != EOF) {
printf("%x \n", ch);
}
```

I have two questions:

1. My understanding is if the file does not exist in the above mentioned path, then fopen should return a NULL. Observation is : even if the file does not exist in the above path (/prj/vlsi/....) , fopen is returning some value and then it goes to while loop trying to print the content. Why is this happening? My main.c and the hex file are residing in the same path. But still I tried giving the complete path which also gave the same results (i.e. even if file does not exist it is returning a non zero pointer value)
2. When the code executes while loop, it prints "FF" indefinitely. It should be because of reason stated above.

Please help to know the issue and how to debug these kind of issues ?

Comment: On `fopen` failure, use `perror` (or `errno`) to understand the reason of the failure

Comment: Use scanf(), because reading char by char involves much more work - you also have to manage those `0x` and spaces.

Comment: Have you checked to see if your build folder is clean, i.e., the file that you are trying to open is not located in the build folder.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `int` instead of a `char` for `ch`

1) Because `fgetc` returns an `int`

> The C library function int fgetc(FILE *stream) gets the next character
>   (an unsigned char) from the specified stream and advances the position
>   indicator for the stream.

2) Because `EOF` can be defined as some number not representable by `char`

Same for `boot_rom_golden`

Comment: @Craig.Feied,  I don't know if is an answer, because, as far as I understand the `while` loop is reached in his code (`fopen` was successful: _while loop, it prints "FF" indefinitely_)

Comment: But that was exactly his question: how can the `while` loop be reached if the file does not exist? It should be impossible, and it is impossible on my system.

Comment: Yes, that sounds very odd ... maybe the file remains on cache even when deleted or  using a wrong path or not showing the real code ...

Answer (score 0):

When I compile and run your code on my system it behaves as you would expect: `myFile` becomes a null pointer and the null test causes an early exit. On your machine, `myFile == NULL` is not true, and the early exit does not occur.

I deduce that either the code you are actually executing is not the same as the code you posted, or there is something going on in your environment that is different from mine.

Can you trace through this line by line?

Are you certain that the file named does not exist on your system at the moment this is being executed?

Perhaps there is truncation occurring? Try a short path and short filename.

Try an absolute filepath rather than a relative one.

Null is likely a macro -- perhaps it's not what you think? Try `if(myFile)` as an alternate.

If not resolved, post more info about your system, and tell us what `myFile` is when your system does not think it's equal to NULL.